# Intento agregar una Agencia a un ArrayList de otra clase pero me salta el Error StackOverFlowError

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo en una clase que se encarga de validar los datos de la agencia introducida

Clase JunitTest

```
class PruebaProyectoTest {

    @Test
    public void testAgregar() {

        Agencia agencia1 = null;
        Agencia agencia2 = new Agencia(null, "NOMBRE", "14700", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia3 = new Agencia("000001", "NOMBRE", null, "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia4 = new Agencia("00001", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia5 = new Agencia("000001", "nombre", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia6 = new Agencia("000001", null, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia7 = new Agencia("000002", "nombre", "abc", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia8 = new Agencia("000002", "NOMBRE", "14700", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        Agencia agencia9 = new Agencia("000002", "NOMBRE", "14700", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        PruebaProyecto tester = new PruebaProyecto();

        assertEquals(true, tester.agregarAgencia(agencia9));

    }
}
```

clase Valida

```
public class Valida {

    private final Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{6}");
    private Matcher comparar;
    private PruebaProyecto comprobador = new PruebaProyecto();

    /**
     * Metodo que permite validar los datos de una agencia
     * 
     * @param agencia agencia a validar los datos
     * @return true en caso de los datos esten correctos
     */
    public boolean validaDatosAgencia(Agencia agencia) {
        if (agencia == null || agencia.getStrCod() == null) {
            System.out.println("Null");
            return false;
        }
        this.comparar = this.patron.matcher(agencia.getStrCod());
        if (agencia.getStrCod().isEmpty() || !comparar.matches() || !(agencia.getStrCod().length() == 6)) {
            System.out.println("err");
            return false;
        }
        if (agencia.getStrCP() == null || agencia.getStrCP() == "" || !agencia.getStrCP().matches("[0-9]{5}")
                || !(agencia.getStrCP().length() == 5)) {
            System.out.println("error");
            return false;
        }

        if (agencia.getStrNombreAgencia() == null || agencia.getStrNombreAgencia() == ""
                || !agencia.getStrNombreAgencia().matches("[A-Za-z]*")) {
            System.out.println("EL");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



}
```

Clase PruebaProyecto

```
public class PruebaProyecto {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Valida validador = new Valida();
    // private static PruebaProyecto test = new PruebaProyecto();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


    /**
     * 
     * Metodo que permite agregar una Agencia
     * 
     * @return true en caso de que la agencia se haya agregado correctamente
     * @throws AgenciaExistenteException Se lanzara la excepcion en caso de que la
     *                                   agencia ya exista
     */
    public boolean agregarAgencia(Agencia agencia) {

        boolean boValidador = validador.validaDatosAgencia(agencia);
        if (!Lista.agencias.contains(agencia)) {
            if (boValidador) {
                Lista.agencias.add(agencia);
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ha ocurrido algun error");
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error:  La agencia ya existe");
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Clase Lista

```
public class Lista {

    public static ArrayList<Agencia> agencias = new ArrayList<Agencia>();
    public static ArrayList<Envio> envios = new ArrayList<Envio>();
    public static ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    public static ArrayList<Recogida> recogidas = new ArrayList<Recogida>();
    public static ArrayList<Repartidor> repartidores = new ArrayList<Repartidor>();
    public static ArrayList<Incidencia> incidencias = new ArrayList<Incidencia>();
    public static ArrayList<TipoEst> tipoEstados = new ArrayList<TipoEst>();
    public static ArrayList<RecEstado> recEstados = new ArrayList<RecEstado>();
    public static ArrayList<EnvEstado> envEstados = new ArrayList<EnvEstado>();
    public static ArrayList<EnvInc> envIncidencias = new ArrayList<EnvInc>();
    public static ArrayList<RecInc> recIncidencias = new ArrayList<RecInc>();
    public static ArrayList<DirHabitual> dirHabituales = new ArrayList<DirHabitual>();



}
```

Clase Agencia

```
public class Agencia extends Persona {

    private String strNombreAgencia;

    /**
     * Metodo Constructor por defecto de la clase sin parametros
     */
    public Agencia() {
    }

    /**
     * Metodo constructor donde se inicializaran los valores de las propiedades de
     * la clase
     * 
     * @param strCod    Codigo que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param strNom    Nombre que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param strCP     Codigo postal que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param strPob    Poblacion que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param strProv   Provincia que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param strVia    Via que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param intNumVia Numero de la via que se asignara a la agencia
     * @param strPiso   Piso que se asigna a la agencia
     * @param strLetra  Letra del piso que se asigna a la agencia
     */
    public Agencia(String strCod, String strNombreAgencia, String strCP, String strPob, String strProv,
            String strTipoVia, String strNomVia, String intNumVia, String strPiso, String strLetra) {
        super(strCod, strCP, strPob, strProv, strTipoVia, strNomVia, intNumVia, strPiso, strLetra);
        this.strNombreAgencia = strNombreAgencia;
    }

    public String getStrNombreAgencia() {
        return strNombreAgencia;
    }

    public void setStrNombreAgencia(String strNombreAgencia) {
        this.strNombreAgencia = strNombreAgencia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Agencia [" + super.toString() + " strNombreAgencia " + strNombreAgencia + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Agencia)
            return this.getStrCod().trim().equals(((Agencia) obj).getStrCod().trim());
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Clase Persona

```
public class Persona {

    private String strCod;
    private String strCP;
    private String strPob;
    private String strProv;
    private String strTipoVia;
    private String strNomVia;
    private String strPiso;
    private String strLetra;
    private String strNumVia;

    public Persona() {

    }

    public Persona(String strCod, String strCP, String strPob, String strProv, String strTipoVia, String strNomVia,
            String strNumVia, String strPiso, String strLetra) {
        this.strCod = strCod;
        this.strCP = strCP;
        this.strPob = strPob;
        this.strProv = strProv;
        this.strTipoVia = strTipoVia;
        this.strNumVia = strNumVia;
        this.strNomVia = strNomVia;
        this.strPiso = strPiso;
        this.strLetra = strLetra;
    }

    public String getStrCod() {
        return strCod;
    }

    public String getStrCP() {
        return strCP;
    }

    public String getStrPob() {
        return strPob;
    }

    public String getStrProv() {
        return strProv;
    }

    public String getStrTipoVia() {
        return strTipoVia;
    }

    public String getStrNomVia() {
        return strNomVia;
    }

    public String getStrPiso() {
        return strPiso;
    }

    public String getStrLetra() {
        return strLetra;
    }

    public void setStrCod(String strCod) {
        this.strCod = strCod;
    }

    public void setStrCP(String strCP) {
        this.strCP = strCP;
    }

    public void setStrPob(String strPob) {
        this.strPob = strPob;
    }

    public void setStrProv(String strProv) {
        this.strProv = strProv;
    }

    public void setStrTipoVia(String strTipoVia) {
        this.strTipoVia = strTipoVia;
    }

    public String getStrNumVia() {
        return strNumVia;
    }

    public void setStrNumVia(String strNumVia) {
        this.strNumVia = strNumVia;
    }

    public void setStrNomVia(String strNomVia) {
        this.strNomVia = strNomVia;
    }

    public void setStrPiso(String strPiso) {
        this.strPiso = strPiso;
    }

    public void setStrLetra(String strLetra) {
        this.strLetra = strLetra;
    }

}
```

Error que salio:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError

at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Currency.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.locale.provider.NumberFormatProviderImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.util.locale.provider.NumberFormatProviderImpl.getNumberInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.useLocale(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.dinaprise.proyecto.prueba.main.PruebaProyecto.<init>(PruebaProyecto.java:10)
at com.dinaprise.prueba.junit.Valida.<init>(Valida.java:19)
at com.dinaprise.proyecto.prueba.main.PruebaProyecto.<init>
```

Y se sigue repitiendo

Comment: Añade la pila completa del error (stacktrace) a la pregunta, por favor

Comment: No especifica error, lanza esto de una y aunque le de a debug cuando llega a la linea assertEquals lanza el error y no sale ni en la consola

Comment: @PabloLozano se refiere a la imagen al final de la pregunta. En vez de la imagen debiste poner el texto completo de la traza del error. No comprendo por qué ahora dices que no da error, en la imagen se ve claramente que dice: `Failure trace` y aparecen problemas con la clase `Scanner` por ejemplo.

Comment: Tendría que ver las clases PruebaProyecto y Valida, que parecen llamarse mutuamente y parecen provocar el error

Comment: Subo todas las clases relacionadas error

Comment: Por favor pon todo el texto de la traza de error. Al poner la imagen sólo se puede ver una parte del mensaje y a veces hay información muy útil ahí que podemos ver para ayudarte. Para trazas de error y para código evita siempre las imágenes. Además si alguien está en un dispositivo con pantalla pequeña, no puede ayudarte con el problema.

Comment: Ya he encontrado el fallo,gracias por la ayuda, parece que ha sido proque creaba un objeto que no usaba

Answer (score 2):

Cada vez que creas una instancia de `PruebaProyecto`, se crea una instancia de `Valida`. Y cada vez que creas una instancia de `Valida`, se crea una instancia de `PruebaProyecto`. Tienes un ciclo de creación infinito que produce ese error.